# Makefile не обнаруживает заданную цель

Tags: makefile

Пишу реализацию HashMap. Makefile писал вручную.

```
SHELL       := /bin/bash
PROJ_ROOT   = $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
MAKEFILE        = Makefile
DEL_FILE        = rm -f
SRC_DIR     = $(PROJ_ROOT)src
CITYHASH_SRC_DIR = $(SRC_DIR)/cityhash
TESTS_SRC_DIR   = $(PROJ_ROOT)test
BUILD_DIR   = $(PROJ_ROOT)build
LIB_BUILD_DIR   = $(BUILD_DIR)/lib
TESTS_BUILD_DIR = $(PROJ_ROOT)build/test

LIB_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
LIB_OBJS    = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/.cpp.o%, $(LIB_SOURCES))
LIB     = $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/libhashmap.so

TEST_SOURCES    = $(wildcard $(TESTS_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
TESTS_OBJS  = $(patsubst $(TESTS_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(TESTS_BUILD_DIR)/.cpp.o%, $(TEST_SOURCES))
TESTS       = $(patsubst $(TESTS_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(TESTS_BUILD_DIR)/%, $(TEST_SOURCES))

CITYHASH_OBJ    = $(TESTS_BUILD_DIR)/city.cc.o

CXX     = g++
INCLUDE_DIRS    = $(SRC_DIR)
CXX_FLAGS   = -std=c++14 -I$(INCLUDE_DIRS) -Wall -g -O3
CXX_LFLAGS  = -std=c++14 -Wall -g -O3 -L$(LIB_BUILD_DIR)

lib: $(LIB)

tests: tests_clean $(CITYHASH_OBJ) $(LIB) $(TESTS)

#$(CITYHASH_OBJ):
$(TESTS_BUILD_DIR)/city.cc.o: $(CITYHASH_SRC_DIR)/city.cc
    $(CXX) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

#$(LIB):  # во время выполнения зависимости этой цели...
$(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/libhashmap.so: $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o
    $(CXX) -shared $(CXX_LFLAGS) -o $@ $^

#$(LIB_OBJS): # Не может обнаружить эту цель
$(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

#$(TESTS_OBJS):
$(TESTS_BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o: $(TESTS_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

#$(TESTS):  
$(TESTS_BUILD_DIR)/%: $(TESTS_BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o $(TESTS_BUILD_DIR)/city.cc.o
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o $@ $^
    @echo 'run a test: ' $@ 
    @$@
    @if [[ $$? == 0 ]]; then \
        echo "Test: '`basename $@`' Completed Succesfully!"; \
    else \
        echo "Test: '`basename $@`' Failed!"; \
    fi

tests_clean:
    $(DEL_FILE) $(TESTS_BUILD_DIR)/*

clean: tests_clean
    $(DEL_FILE) $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/*

watch:
    $(foreach v, $(.VARIABLES), $(info $(v) = $($(v))))
```

При попытке выполнить `make tests` 
make выводит ошибку:

```
make: *** Нет правила для сборки цели «cpp_hashmap/build/lib/%.cpp.o»,  
требуемой для «cpp_hashmap/build/lib/libhashmap.so».  Останов.
```

Однако цель указана, проверял на предмет опечатки, всё совпадает. Не знаю даже, в какую сторону копать.

Можете посмотреть сами, [ссылка на репозиторий github](https://github.com/oupjob/cpp_hashmap). 
Только перед сборкой нужно выполнить:
`mkdir -p build/{test,lib}`
в корне проекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял, потому что цель - одиночный файл, а написал так, что происходило сопоставление со списком (на каждый правый файл должен быть отдельный файл слева), так нужно делать если только генерируешь объектники для исходникв.

Заменил `$(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o` на `$(LIB_OBJS)` и заработало.

Правильный вариант (только city.cc.o теперь собирается в $(LIB_BUILD_DIR))

```
$(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/libhashmap.so: $(LIB_OBJS) $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/city.cc.pic.o 
    $(CXX) -shared $(CXX_LFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```